# php foreach loop is doing strange behaviuor to add values

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors, foreach

I am just getting value of a product in foreach loop.Now the logic is something like this when I will get the product amount it will be inserted to the input area of a form and when the button add to cart will be clicked that product quantity will be shown in checkout page.. The code inside foreach loop is like this

```
 ![<div class="cart">
    <table class="discount-prices">
      <tr>
        <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
          <td class="discount-price">
            <?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount\['quantity'\], $discount\['price'\]); ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div>
        <?php echo $text_qty; ?>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $discount\['quantity'\]; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
        &nbsp;<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" />
     </div>
    <?php } ?>]
```

The jQuery script which is working for the button is like this

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                //$('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
                setTimeout(opencartpage(),1000);
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Now here the problem is when I am doing click on the first add to cart button it is going to the checkout page but the value is taking is 5 not 3.You can see in the image(second image) I have clicked on the first button whose value is '3' but it is taking '5'(last value).
Another problem is the first button for add to cart is working for checkout page but two another buttons for add to cart are not working at all. When click on the two rest of buttons nothing happening. So can some one help me and tell me what is the wrong part here?
[image][image]

**Update**

using `$('.button-cart')` instead of `$('#button-cart')` is making all the buttons active means when clicked on that button it is processing to the checkout page but it is taking only the last value that is 5 which can be seen in the 1st image. So how to solve this problem?

Comment: why do you have to escape this one `<?php echo $discount\['quantity'\]; ?>`

Comment: Discount product quantity to be filled there automatically after fetching from the database

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind the jQuery event to #button-cart, use .button-cart instead. CSS is pretty relaxed about matching ids (ie it will still match them all), but jQuery is not so forgiving - it will only bind an event matching an id to ONE of the matching elements in the DOM.

Also, the ajax data looks to be sending all the .product-info elements, not just the ones linked to the button. This is untested, but try something like:

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: $self.children(...),
        ...
    });
```

Comment: using .button-cart is doing all the buttons working but now the problem is all the buttons are taking the last value and that is '5' that you can see from the 1st image.

Comment: What data is the php script on the other end of your ajax call receiving?